# Entropy Change in Radiation and Convection

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, radiation, thermal-radiation, convection

When a system loses it's internal thermal energy by emitting **radiation** or by **convection** what is change of the systems entropy mathematically?

I saw this [question's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/does-radiation-change-entropy) answers for radiation only but still unclear because it doesn't clearly answers my question. Can someone clarify it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Entropy of a system is a function of the state of the system (i.e., a physical property of the system), and is independent of any process path that caused it to arrive at that state.  Therefore, whether a system lost energy and arrived at a given state by radiation, convection, or conduction is immaterial.  The entropy change is determined only by the starting state and the final state, and nothing in between.

Comment: But how can I mathematically show that in convection and radiation, entropy always increase?

Comment: If that is the only method by which the temperature increases, then what you are saying is that the final state has a higher temperature than the initial state.  So what you are really asking is that, "if the only difference between the initial state and the final state is an increase in temperature, how do I know that the entropy increased?"  Is that what you really mean?

Comment: Yes, I want to say if heat is conducted by means of these, how can I mathematically prove that the system's entropy is also increased?

Comment: I don't know how to prove this using statistical thermodynamics.  But, using classical thermodynamics, $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}}$$Would that be able to satisfy you?

Comment: Classical mechanics is fine. But do how we prove it using the formula you presented?

Comment: No problem.  You start out by devising a reversible process path between the initial and final temperatures of the system, $T_i$ and $T_f$.  I'm not going to detail what that path is, but, for the reversible path, $dQ_{rev}=mCdT$ where m is the mass of the material and C is its heat capacity.  If we carry out the integration using this, we obtain $$\Delta S=mC\ln{(T_f/T_i)}$$This is positive if $T_f>T_i$.

Comment: why reversible? isn't in reversible process change in entropy is zero?

Comment: In a reversible process, the change in entropy of the system *plus the surroundings* is equal to zero.  The entropy change of either of them alone does not have to be zero.  Their changes are equal in magnitude and opposite in sign.  Whoever is teaching you this stuff is doing a terrible job.

Comment: I am sorry about that. But I want to consider a system where a hot reservoir and a cold reservoir is part of the same system and is in contact, isolated from rest of the universe. Then in a reversible process, would the change in entropy be zero?

Comment: The process you describe is not reversible, no matter how many times you try to ascribe it as being reversible.  For this isolated system, the process of transferring heat between the reservoirs by placing them in contact is irreversible, and its entropy change is positive.

Comment: One question, sir. Can I apply the change in entropy for convection and radiation is $$\Delta S = \frac{Q}{T_2}- \frac{Q}{T_1}$$?

Comment: As I said, the heat transfer mechanism that caused the change in state of each of the two reservoirs is irrelevant.